# Shortcut MacOS to go to the beginning of a document

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Specifically as an example, I have a pdf document with 1000 pages and I'm in the page number 400 .. I want have a shortcut to move to the page number 1 and the page number 1000 ...

Is there any keyboard shortcut In MacOS to move to the begin and the end of a document no matter which third party app is running such as a pdf Reader, word document or any other software?

Comment: `Command-up/down arrow` seems to work for most general apps.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no universal shortcut. But Preview provides for this with the "home" and "end" keys (on an extended keyboard). Another handy Preview shortcut is CMD-OPT-G, which brings up a tiny dialog where you enter the page number you wish to display.

For Word, or other apps, you might try creating your own shortcuts: System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts . . . App Shortcuts.

G'luck.